# Is it possible to write a query that categorize sum(amount) in 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have MyTbl like this

```
Id  type    amount
--  ----    ------
1   1       100
2   1       200
3   2       300
4   2       400
```

Is it possible to write a query for sqlite in Android that returns this?

```
Amount1 Amount2
------- -------
300     700
```

I have written the following query but it is not ok:

```
select SUM(a.amount) as Amount1, SUM(b.amount) as Amount2 from MyTbl a inner join MyTbl b
on a.id = b.id
group by a.type
```

it returns:

```
Amount1 Amount2
------- -------
300     300
700     700
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) amount1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) amount2
FROM MyTbl
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/89bda/3/0)